# Setting the coordinates in a QGIS layout right

Tags: qgis, coordinates, layouts, grids-graticules

Apparently the coordinates of my map are false. They are supposed to be something around 53°N/ 12° E. I am using a WMS Layer. How do I get the coordinates right? [image: screenshot of the grid's item properties]

Comment: If you choose to use the EPSG:3035 coordinates are they correct?   (forgetting the transformation to degrees).  Wondering whether the issue centres on incorrect axis ordering somewhere EPSG:3035 is Northing/Easting order. https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/3035

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From CRS choose WGS:84, EPSG:4326.

Then for interval put 0.1.

Answer (score 8):

You have asked for the format of your grid to be Degrees, Minutes and Seconds which is not appropriate for a grid in metres (EPSG:3035) - if you set it to decimal you will get the expected output in metres

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to use Degrees, Minutes and Seconds then you should set your CRS to EPSG:4326 and the distance between lines to 10 (or 5).

[image]