# Drawing the right coordinates in my grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grids-graticules

I'm trying to put the numbers of system of coordinate in my map using WGS84/18S. All my shapes are in that projection and I'm using units of the map around 1500 point in "x" and "y" but, I think those aren't the right coordinates.

When I use just WGS 84, the numbers are correct. Maybe with general projection it works, but with a specific one it doesn't work, I don't know.

[image]

Comment: By “grilll” I think you mean graticule or a measured grid.

Comment: Yes, you're right, thank you.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/378857/79 for an explanation and solution to your issue